# How to flip UV map

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to flip this UV, but not just flip it's current position, flip it based on the whole texture sheet if that makes sense.

For example, I have this face mapped:
[image]

and I want to flip the UV so it matches at the same texture at the bottom when I flip the texture sheet:

[image]

I know i can easily slide the UV down, but I want to know if there is a way to flip it exactly.

Comment: On sidebar/view, set the cursor location to 0.5,0.5; set pivot point to cursor; scale by -1 in Y axis.

Comment: cheers that worked!!!